# XCode autocompletion: Is it possible to suggest "NSString" when I typed "NSS"?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, autocomplete

XCode suggest me "NSSet" when I typed "NSS". It is not very good for me. I use NSString quite often.
Is it possible to suggest "NSString" when I typed "NSS"?

Comment: There is always the possibility to use another editor, like `emacs` or `vi` ...

Comment: but with `emacs` or `vim` there is no auto-complete for in-built methods & API's of iOS. And those API names are huuuuugggee.... So using xCode is highly recommended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type `NSString` into the editor, select that and drag it with your mouse to Code Snippet Library (⌃⌥⌘2 if not open), then set its completion shortcut to something not used by Xcode, like "foo".

[image: custom code snippet]

Now every time you want to use `NSString` just type `foo` and Xcode will offer to auto-complete with `NSString`. It requires some time to get used to typing something else just like with macro Srikar suggested, but it doesn't add anything new to code itself.

BTW, related comic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tcxD.png

Comment: Actually, the completion shortcut can be `NSS`, which is easy to type. Another variant is a upgrade to the ["xNSString"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9043750/38557) suggestion -- set the shortcut to `xNSString`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any direct way to affect the first-shown suggestion.

However, you can always choose from the many other selections shown, or even easier, just type "NSSt".

Comment: `NSSt` like in `NSStream` :-) Unfortunately you have to type `NSStri`. Plain annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I know this is really irritating. I use `NSString` way more often than `NSSet` & apparently xCode does not take frequency of usage & no ranking of auto-suggest thereof.

I used to use one way to circumvent through this. Its kind of a hack, but as programmers without hacks where are we ;)

I used to create macros. So you could create one like so -

`#define xNSString NSString`

This way xCode auto-suggest is morphed into suggesting what you need.